# Preventing guests from seeing an Adsense pop-up before entering my site

Tags: google-adsense, pop-up, internet-abuse

Back in the day, guests could visit any website of their choosing through any search engine without advertisements stopping their way. It seems now that's not the case for users on specific devices and/or machines. My old phone with opera 7.5 is one of them.

**Here's the issue**

When I use my phone to browse pages and one page is a search result from google.com, I occasionally see a random advertisement pop-up on the screen (and yes, the text in the title bar is "Adsense"), and because my phone screen size is small, I have to scroll to the bottom and click the continue button to continue on to the page. This doesn't happen if I hardly visit Google at all (for example, if I used Duckduckgo search engine). It makes me think Google wants to own everyone.

Since I am a webmaster myself, I don't want my guests (including those with an IQ of 1) to go to my site expecting a picture from the site, only to find out they see a random advertisement served by Adsense which they must see before continuing. If Google keeps doing this to people, then people will become more frustrated overtime. It's worse than loading a site and having a pop-up be displayed in the center.

I do admit that I use Adsense on my site, however the only style of ads I use are the old-fashioned in-page ads where the ad loads inside a portion of the page, yet the user can easily scroll past it.

**Here's my question**

Is there something I can do as a Webmaster to prevent people from seeing the pop-up ads when they want to access my site regardless of where they were on the internet before accessing the site?

I mean if there's a simple HTTP code I can insert in the served pages to stop this Google Adsense madness from happening, I'd insert it right away.

Then again, I could add extra messages to my site telling people that random pop-ups are caused by Google, but at the same time, that could hurt Google and confuse guests even more.

So if there's anything I can do as a webmaster to prevent guests from seeing a random advertisement (by Adsense) cover their entire screen and forcing the user to click the continue button at the bottom before continuing to my site, I'd like to know.

Comment: Popups, yikes yuk.

Comment: Where is this ad served from?   Is it from AdSense on your site or is it from the search engine before they leave?

Comment: In all tests in which I've seen the ad, my site was never involved. it just appears randomly.

Answer (score 2):

*A simple jQuery solution would be to use:*

```
$(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 639) {
      setTimeout(function(){
         $("#adsense-container").delay(15000).fadeIn(500); // 15 Second Delay
      });
    } else {
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#adsense-container").delay(1000).fadeIn(500); // 1 Second Delay
      });
    }
  }).resize();
});
```

*If you prefer not to use JavaScript, then you can use CSS3 animations:*

```
<div class="adsense-container">
    <!-- Your Adsense Code -->
</div>

.adsense-container {
    -webkit-animation: adsense-anim 15s;
    -moz-animation: adsense-anim 15s;
    -o-animation: adsense-anim 15s;
    animation: adsense-anim 15s;
    opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes adsense-anim {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    49% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes adsense-anim {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    49% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes adsense-anim {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    49% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes adsense-anim {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    49% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes adsense-anim {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    49% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

But I still think any popup is YUK unless a user purposely activates it.

Comment: I think what you're suggesting is a way to modify my adsense blocks on my site. What I'm trying to do is prevent google from deciding to issue a random adsense ad pop-up before guests even visit my site.

Comment: I was suggesting you a solution.